# Infinite Threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

The following code is the init function from a Kivy app I'm coding. The app utilises Kivy's built-in Clock method to call an update function every 10 seconds. The update function runs cpu intensive code so I use a function within the init function to run the update function in it's own thread. This code does what I want it to do but it occurred to me that each time the update function gets called, a new unique thread is created.

My Questions:

- Are there any problems or issues associated with a potentially infinite number of threads being created?
- Is there a method that stops or destroys a thread before the new one is created? If so is that approach advisable or does it matter if infinite threads get created?
- Is there a better way to code this?

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        def start_thread(dt):    
        
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.update)
            t.start()    

        Clock.schedule_interval(start_thread, 10)

def update(self):
            
        "Does some stuff in new thread every time it's called"
```

Comment: It annoys the heck out of me (and probably most mathematicians) when people say things like "a potentially infinite number of threads being created". You could run for a trillion years, creating a trillion threads every picosecond, and you will get nowhere *near* an infinite number of threads :-) [/end rant]

Comment: A way is to use a variable shared by threads indicating that an update is running. With variable a new thread will know to do nothing and be ended. The variable is set/reset by the first thread that see it not set. In ten the worst case you may miss one update but it depends if it matters for your use case. Also, 1 thread every 10 seconds is 3 millions per year so far away from infinite.

Comment: IDK, Sometimes, "infinite" is just a synonym for "unlimited." Nothing _in the program_ limits how long it will go on creating new threads.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to code this?

Use a thread pool. *Pooling* is when we re-use objects instead of continually creating and destroying new ones. A *thread* pool uses a small collection of "worker" threads to perform *tasks* (callable objects) that your program submits to it.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor